# How to interpret $\sum_{1 \le i , j\le n} $?

Tags: summation

I have issues with understanding the exact meaning of $\sum_{1 \le i , j\le n} $. For example, how do I have to read the following combination of symbols?

> $$\sum_{1 \le i , j\le n} a_i b_i \langle u_i, u_j \rangle$$

Comment: It's the sum of all terms $a_ib_i\langle u_i,u_j\rangle$ such that $1\le i\le n$ **and** $1\le j\le n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is to be interpreted as:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i \langle u_i, u_j \rangle \right)$$

or equivalently:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_i b_i \langle u_i, u_j \rangle \right)$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to write $ \sum_{i, j =1}^n a_i b_i \langle u_i, u_j \rangle$ then?

Comment: @Julian of course it is notationally convenient to write it as you have done. But in your question you ask for clarifications on how to read it, and that is what Ahmed did. Basically, all there is to it is a collapse of the sum symbols $\sum$, to avoid an overload of notation.

Comment: Yes, I know. :) It's just that our professor always uses the notation above, so I thought that this was the convenient notation.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Think about first what $\left(\displaystyle\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}1\right)$ means.

It is nothing but a truncated way of writing the double sum $\left (\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n 1\right )$, which equals $n\times n=n^2$.

Compare this to something like $\left(\displaystyle\sum_{1\leq i\neq j\leq n}1\right)$, which is simply $ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \displaystyle\sum_{\substack {j=1 \\ i\neq j}}^n 1 =n(n-1)=(n)_2$,

or $\displaystyle\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}1=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \displaystyle\sum_{\substack {j=1 \\ j>i}}^n 1=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}={n\choose 2}$